# How to resolve package not found error when trying to make the composer get the latest package versions?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am using symfony2 with composer. http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

i want that for all the plugins in composer.json , i always get the latest build of the package

I tried this i get error

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "dev-master*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
```

The error is

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package twig/extensions dev-master* could not be found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version to use for twig/extensions is `dev-master`, but you used `dev-master*`. Remove the wildcard at the end and it should work better.

Comment: my composer.json uses `"twig/extensions": "~1.1.0"` (default for my install of symfony). I assume that's different than the regular twig, because when I do composer update for symfony 2.5, it updates twig to 1.16 automatically, but I don't see where it fetches that from.

Comment: symfony itself requires twig, and twig/extensions requires twig as well, so yes it will upgrade it unless you require it in a very specific version. That said twig is pretty strict about BC in the 1.x versions so it's not an issue to upgrade, you just get new features and fixes.

Comment: So if I needed a feature in Twig 1.5 I would need to manually add Twig to my `composer.json`, because Symfony and Twig/Extension is going to set that to the lowest "required" version possible? e.g. Symfony `composer.json` has `"require": { "twig/twig": "~1.12" }`