# How to get composer to update version numbers to the latest ones available in composer.json?

Tags: composer-php

In my `composer.json` config file, I have:

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-log" : "~2.3",
 },
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.4"
 }
```

I want:

```
"require": {
   "zendframework/zend-log" : "^2.9",
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.2"
 }
```

Note the version number changes

How?  I want it to be done automatically without me having to look up each individual latest version that's available and edit it manually.

There is this question but it does not help: [How to resolve package not found error when trying to make the composer get the latest package versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302326/how-can-i-make-the-composer-to-get-the-latest-version-in-composer-json)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run

```
composer require zendframework/zend-log
```

and

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: what if I have more packages? do I run this for every package?

Comment: you can do `composer require package1 package2 package3 --flags`.

Comment: You may occasionally run into issues where a dependent package will have conflicts with something that's locked. You may wish to use the `--with-all-dependencies` (or `-W`) option to help.

Comment: see my answer for doing it for all composer.json packages.

Answer (score 14):

Since **Composer 2.4**, there's a **`bump` command** that does exactly that.

Quoted from the [release announcement](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-4/) (Jordi Boggiano for Packagist; Aug 2022):

> The new `bump` command lets you increase your requirements to match the versions currently installed. For example, if you require package `"foo/bar": "^1"` – but you currently have `foo/bar 1.5.3` installed – running `composer bump foo/bar` will update your composer.json requirement to `"foo/bar": "^1.5.3"`.

*c.f. ["Bumping your version constraints more easily"](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-4/#bumping-your-version-constraints-more-easily)*

Comment: Cool. Although in the OP example, that would update phpunit from 5.4 to the latest 5.x release, right? It won't update to the latest

Comment: It will update the constraint to the latest version that matches the old constraint. It won't perform a major upgrade

Comment: Actually, this updates composer.json to match current installed versions in composer.lock. I.e., it doesn't update to newer versions of the packages (that would require running `composer update` first)

Answer (score 6):

For all packages in composer.json (without dev dependencies), you can do it with the following command:

```
composer show --no-dev --direct --name-only \
  | xargs composer require
```

And for all developer dependencies:

```
grep -F -v -f \
    <(composer show --direct --no-dev --name-only | sort) \
    <(composer show --direct --name-only | sort) \
  | xargs composer require --dev
```

The combination of both commands is similar to what npm-check-updates ([ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)) would do for NPM.

Answer (score 1):

You can install this tool and use this

https://github.com/khanakia/pcu and then run this command

```
pcu check -u
```