# How to update/sync composer.json with entries from composer.lock

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning, packagist

I have following in my `composer.json`

```
{
  "require": {
       "vendor/package": "^2.0.0", // but installed 2.1.1 because of the ^
   }
}
```

how do I update/sync the `composer.json` from `composer.lock` to have the latest installed/exact version `"vendor/package": "^2.1.1"` I also have quite a few packages, updating it by hand is tedious.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could `composer bump` help?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197446/how-to-get-composer-to-update-version-numbers-to-the-latest-ones-available-in-co helps to resolve your problem?

Comment: `composer bump` was the answer I was looking for

Comment: You can use `composer bump`, as said, but you don't normally need it. `composer.lock` alone is what provides the feature to set a specific version. Updating `composer.json` just means that you're declaring that any other version (e.g. 2.1.0) will not work. Since that's often not true, it can be confusing for your colleagues and your future self.